# How to remove annotations/labels on ComplexHeatmap

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap, complexheatmap

The plot is generated using ComplexHeatmap. I would like to achieve the following:

1. Remove the right-most annotation. This annotation is randomly generated and I'm not sure which part of my code is responsible for it.
2. Remove the bottom annotation because it is redundant

Code:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
row_km = ncol(met.resolv)-1
ha = rowAnnotation(foo = anno_empty(border = FALSE, 
                                    width = max_text_width(unlist(colnames(met.resolv))) + unit(row_km, "mm")))
Heatmap(t(as.matrix(met.resolv)), name = "mat", row_km = row_km, right_annotation = ha)
for(i in 1:row_km) {
  decorate_annotation("foo", slice = i, {
    grid.rect(x = 0, width = unit(2, "mm"), gp = gpar(fill = i, col = NA), just = "left")
    grid.text(paste(colnames(met.resolv)[[i]], collapse = "\n"), x = unit(4, "mm"), just = "left")
  })
}
dev.off()
```

Data:

```
> dput(met.resolv)
structure(list(Monocytes = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0691477875220381, 
0.0461824156116519, 0.00777223000960038, 0, 0, 0, 0.00165316191239164, 
0.0245461060386295, 0.026342142484403, 0, 0, 0, 0.0362473177899938, 
0, 0, 0.0615459951223746, 0, 0.0294951710325671, 0, 0.0592412716587455, 
0, 0, 0.0123687180331427, 0.0349610490875464, 0, 0, 0.0120447100747868, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0605654493960397, 0, 0, 0, 0.0156948837618427, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0162458259966668, 0.0400325997973774, 0.0646813979247544, 
0.105695364068571, 0, 0.029457724435371, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0369713678668627, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0357926269740144, 0, 0.0531263754314151, 
0.0486164035086266, 0.0148702011890504, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0535972381103577, 0.0202495301385591, 0.0536138300587981, 0, 
0, 0.0900351412881403, 0, 0.0341924140937514, 0, 0.113938357187793, 
0.0911502547479112, 0, 0, 0.0228639194163747, 0, 0.026656712773624, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0738174040559262, 0.0165041643639888, 0, 0.106939481279544, 
0, 0.0642190337690739, 0, 0.0546286015763255, 0, 0.0747334596550865, 
0, 0, 0.0355892321089013, 0.0347924298896058, 0, 0, 0, 0.032352893311738, 
0.0819054620775835, 0, 0.0559309564221401, 0, 0.0985419377429262, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00928183689943942, 0, 0.0527418731416131, 0.0134973761685673, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0234976098850193, 0, 0, 0.00482752488838482, 0, 
0, 0.0676859500992485, 0.0442535561285247, 0.00761480212990707, 
0, 0, 0.0853341530881731, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.10559526812316, 
0.0494672521040403, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.079131390869771, 0.0229654854268431, 
0, 0, 0.102427158087248, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0101603293445309, 0, 0.103079086748441, 
0, 0.0125303190320994, 0, 0.0661437588642447, 0, 0, 0, 0.0561794334532523, 
0, 0.0327890963318976, 0, 0.0419068594102123, 0, 0.067423071541282, 
0, 0, 0.0187185773041594, 0.0329453505144321, 0.0610622360157104, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037257889757221, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Dendritic Cells` = c(0, 
0, 0.00772620422001257, 0, 0, 0, 0.0480402297895918, 0, 0, 0.00898992233305366, 
0.057888955860833, 0.0362367878235371, 0, 0.0472205793224695, 
0.0286203273050095, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0943413656490886, 0, 0, 
0.00991071586093427, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0109231267098435, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0470379238483922, 0.0399623964994193, 0, 0.0398951093128132, 
0, 0.0111473853675537, 0.0434767003759102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.073535043107836, 0.0755612462353139, 0, 0.0953593102456016, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0128608283980755, 0.0314060834919189, 
0.00884831456272853, 0, 0.0884981429773645, 0.0445015368777799, 
0.0754345259319788, 0, 0, 0.060701298412642, 0.0913471882155461, 
0, 0.0452531978570387, 0, 0.049178607487682, 0.0826275639383182, 
0, 0.124093932800728, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0977048087067831, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0672032577641486, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0981964692514739, 
0.0235027801237651, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0748024943368016, 0, 
0.104543963351335, 0.0979388211805319, 0, 0, 0, 0.0401167633457923, 
0.0314482162216529, 0.0442394459174621, 0, 0.0140008861176788, 
0.0232283077806447, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.108741864636673, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.107732044986015, 0.066983613724879, 0, 0, 0.0368563262418387, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.066267137564904, 0, 0, 
0.0675645701271485, 0, 0, 0.0969617440917184, 0.124557736337305, 
0.00610911435446513, 0.0345633572477895, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0863645430412923, 
0, 0.0333337547296488, 0, 0.0507494617092974, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0317393093247079, 0, 0.0563713132097374, 0, 0, 
0.019973078147727, 0.0584739535414952, 0.0889301910028202, 0.0129829233909958, 
0.037127173658058, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0200823869433712, 0.0700885471668096, 
0.0876716112889274, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0849748429076341
), Macrophages = c(0, 0.0664642500649833, 0, 0, 0.0371204658284402, 
0, 0, 0.0225187084795453, 0.0603416047052193, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.0313730144635087, 0.0704265029977412, 0, 0.00934366999330129, 
0.0411264824824766, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0895127214724744, 0.0338874117888457, 
0.0438811824465186, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0463514793532163, 0, 0.00674419444497034, 
0, 0, 0.0358743861448126, 0, 0.106009355015402, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0380955449370628, 
0, 0, 0.108499096415126, 0.0591717798867857, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.031192940686014, 
0.0541954561598978, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.028848918303242, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0763353149697233, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0178690874348837, 
0, 0, 0.00568584039613123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0571330570928271, 
0.0537235256526157, 0, 0, 0.0216592187272257, 0, 0, 0.0489263962935055, 
0, 0.084070178133472, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0492033715633916, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0459024916410738, 0.0696483061816341, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.111431372471552, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0766808174828692, 
0.00198821402025115, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00562951934259748, 
0, 0.0639901499007506, 0.0725598946106698, 0, 0.0741734035283442, 
0, 0, 0.00558809044680591, 0, 0.106634068044244, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0244302506156129, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0734111291380431, 
0, 0, 0.0550655538688119, 0.0858806670851933, 0, 0, 0.0278886936686482, 
0, 0, 0.0957009585676285, 0, 0.026320052620483, 0, 0.0601613480782192, 
0.0784534962000719, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.070251911801093, 0.0977742411523257, 
0.0620341427221682, 0.0229180712884482, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0502226381842951, 
0.0355958907496745, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Neutrophils = c(0.173202855063056, 
0, 0, 0.0643464479529596, 0, 0.0187142163615865, 0.0117918312263748, 
0, 0, 0.115244141262919, 0.0520653071278115, 0.00997874098002133, 
0, 0.00754706466322519, 0.0885236230551497, 0.0144246971006176, 
0.000602296924347016, 0, 0.0195266392400734, 0.00343527794086701, 
0.0438755373867991, 0.0722986077386675, 0.110681132771528, 0, 
0.0351618293579245, 0.00435545703283675, 0, 0, 0, 0.0368866454725712, 
0.0162442920179102, 0, 0.0787773467416015, 0.0579753676730959, 
0.005234657310639, 0, 0.00147499913373734, 0, 0.0381402016683103, 
0, 0, 0.0166566522338995, 0.0419451101470518, 0, 0, 0.00798247423813956, 
0, 0.0596172110951325, 0, 0.0361061659566541, 0, 0, 0.049250431819489, 
0.0434896730618063, 0.0822246188987232, 0.0603202804830778, 0.0131222072447581, 
0.0301454180463505, 0.0147540306593655, 0.0814048872263266, 0.0747191042213935, 
0.0983191091730422, 0, 0, 0.0160417850448892, 0.012043683685235, 
0.0141119882699431, 0.00857174728721042, 0.0777919225911778, 
0, 0.0992344665316159, 0.046212633851779, 0, 0, 0.0396696478789855, 
0.023541311398369, 0.035443602080117, 0.0310170293451452, 0.0385285815079618, 
0.0815047854679873, 0.0571660750658286, 0.0141683272056927, 0.0308615540936258, 
0.0518352730527256, 0, 0.000396346057343118, 0, 0, 0, 0.0538943462668141, 
0.035986038137999, 0.00927075882978976, 0, 0.110887708681284, 
0.139222096574131, 0, 0, 0.0669078935328223, 0, 0.0199177317890421, 
0, 0, 0.0400304052430635, 0, 0.00440525933908184, 0.101316655241951, 
0.0845683933810249, 0.0111147892080765, 0.000194675807831215, 
0.0478122590965676, 0.0108368578658678, 0, 0.00520253232735015, 
0.000666135535914547, 0.0549658985900597, 0.0114000541706753, 
0.0127077787419489, 0.0391334782587811, 0, 0.0209523915960185, 
0.0971913277815389, 0, 0.0469883393767104, 0.0496213842256207, 
0.0359286422237782, 0.0529504734004393, 0, 0, 0, 0.0433961238203703, 
0.021850197557139, 0.0395640549771137, 0.0922334025956585, 0.0483046910371425, 
0.0186216215513106, 0.0550525168229281, 0.088150867999541, 0, 
0, 0.0135543204876098, 0, 0.0989933731364153, 0.0158043768315651, 
0.0183229669895841, 0.0426718271324455, 0.0114891425209301, 0.0659051580358175, 
0.0619953431427377, 0.0482257574952798, 0.0773381803963788, 0.0253741123843225, 
0.0107086487653616, 0.0420949258573128, 0.0281475133831514, 0.060350932539814, 
0.0587785767529495, 0.0404446774024529, 0.125535974712747, 0, 
0.0490282840839015, 0.021052259239552, 0.0611358664090915, 0.00757689010367424, 
0.0507755609753139, 0, 0.0389554090771645, 0.0982478187598233, 
0, 0, 0.0134317472537198, 0, 0.0128006550325235, 0.0505512579943848, 
0, 0, 0.038256250382962, 0.0469265578349334, 0.00334427316061624, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00626392892037603, 0.0440298789182536, 0, 0.0282026295907876, 
0, 0, 0.00150065964875849, 0.0190817478355799, 0, 0.0127828856273365, 
0.014596671906112, 0.0483201124506595, 0.0353342439156698, 0.00672050677948275, 
0, 0.0811705150188624, 0.0493752580566823, 0, 0.0209160294519099, 
0.013752854590642, 0.063501576806459), Eosinophils = c(0, 0.00809451621782635, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0026662337469062, 0.0126433025837339, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00796674767545607, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00499167318989537, 
0.00540473669932436, 0.0132359238774652, 0, 0, 0, 0.0230653974435718, 
0, 0, 0.00432338052789634, 0, 0, 0.0319700803520666, 0, 0.0031987953611015, 
0.0398556247118198, 0, 0, 0.0129125141315489, 0.00436095294550087, 
0, 0.00459436961347775, 0, 0, 0, 0.00418540665451432, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0155568281331729, 0, 0, 0.000298921822970892, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00397942947307469, 0, 0, 0.00326885388352378, 0.0116953989467455, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0091673699760387, 0, 0, 0.0104694343151277, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0106460599468824, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00137226627636973, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0177136011994577, 0, 0, 0.00818482844447488, 0.0111983703276412, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000429504274062156, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00258066443769122, 
0.00306315153517793, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00359656674889014, 0, 
0, 0.0131361572856656, 0.00205192026090814, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00422223508349868, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Regulatory T cells` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00203497813109171, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `Naive T cells` = c(0, 
0.00984426904423764, 0, 0.111694279700795, 0.0123267828167452, 
0.0121761009946946, 0.015487451006506, 0, 0.0231848393777138, 
0, 0.00278269237244245, 0.0200645732264692, 0, 0.0147361795082149, 
0.0526711496398388, 0, 0.00992032127196248, 0, 0, 0.030586635289606, 
0.0194771169333053, 0.0585249045620972, 0.05185410955886, 0.0282712407266747, 
0.047347995836266, 0.0091972873174429, 0.0224689646833595, 0.0168560622651103, 
0.0543543238930381, 0.0699529566098182, 0.0698276607782987, 0.0562257591799179, 
0.0360765379139407, 0.0592002167029107, 0.0156601541889383, 0.0460753740526197, 
0.00405530020957892, 0.0226538590767101, 0.0147492556628515, 
0.0159043222699004, 0.0288008805297882, 0, 0.0442744680422057, 
0.0457404533608017, 0.00812629253361771, 0.0158650458624831, 
0.00635019640136326, 0.00619563509012859, 0.00409128330756032, 
0.0222565055535637, 0, 0, 0.0048237641126488, 0.0173899831815032, 
0.0109053883113337, 0.0262720215318895, 0.120097336088575, 0.0402351206264565, 
0.118835189340634, 0.0108982374155515, 0, 0.0658246229159711, 
0.0891652088411948, 0.133197586666666, 0.0112920330113727, 0.102017066883241, 
0.0265919348481495, 0.0277696502379857, 0.0714869395531033, 0.0423975613058092, 
0.0212693451368019, 0.0263137912602988, 0.122616447610436, 0.109728378596311, 
0.0696703403750373, 0.0392406803860835, 0.0194391057670953, 0.0362819963732356, 
0.0339352509328157, 0.0221280228888688, 0.0102848148566505, 0.00768881738320744, 
0.0174891197723109, 0.0249796467703447, 0, 0.0239495034215299, 
0.0251058278619065, 0.0467234461369119, 0, 0.00971840988376387, 
0.127745538528666, 0.00671674630100788, 0.10240399843569, 0.055141462261278, 
0.0303374200925338, 0.00692154538979957, 0.057670252829454, 0, 
0.0283560939226969, 0.00966246154582358, 0, 0.0592460276900651, 
0.0345573065364568, 0.0198687969190848, 0.0168333021594181, 0.0684055614247141, 
0.0649258632668894, 0.0140977410128865, 0.0244485924575798, 0, 
0.020491568774929, 0.0824755343285868, 0.0121462115984289, 0.000123378747390639, 
0.0308825930932601, 0.00549604973033692, 0.018570516648586, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0434032360989096, 0.0339427941951133, 0.0267866898048314, 
0.0407266098753402, 0.0279422798062132, 0.00663913172410398, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0213152178602798, 0.0105683673605352, 0.0566510520871832, 
0.0773680140710062, 0.0185625676515157, 0.0436239310757379, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0149401556003189, 0.0468651183792376, 0.0104866469683767, 
0.0707288435302495, 0, 0.0675792534247013, 0.0388869256725434, 
0.0130986202215523, 0.0274710447189186, 0.107606073523927, 0.0441171698819717, 
0.0249758361431375, 0.0141881349771224, 0.0265537611905153, 0.0077827151623926, 
0.0134849969462081, 0.041693009995673, 0.0762356193325923, 0.04667274600812, 
0.0308366102239691, 0.016785384456431, 0.0868983254786492, 0.0414612124111827, 
0.0240028138829478, 0, 0.00814986324286261, 0.00506818632916586, 
0.0216439784951879, 0.00648091520924878, 0.00538969869331938, 
0.0170025713718352, 0.01519732544994, 0.0797956970681355, 0.0264510683472749, 
0.0442089770314962, 0, 0.00908564772887047, 0.0346439890653811, 
0, 0.000645238210905506, 0, 0.00483290861055564, 0.0268477355936362, 
0.000510404928012844, 0.0127313403158118, 0.00299295616873856, 
0.00332814989575813, 0.0158858130780054, 0, 0.0120829464480978, 
0.00440446186071305, 0.0162353498976662, 0.0204270133699353, 
0.0340501135616326, 0.0052719785334478, 0.103942784646269, 0.00537625372862649, 
0.00929869504860026, 0.02556681845282, 0.0192627743037254, 0, 
0.00617139649414258, 0.0103424413180418, 0.0228607636192383), 
    `Memory T cells` = c(0, 0.0312258875142767, 0.124409625779986, 
    0, 0.0135351004994425, 0.0537156172200875, 0.0540049513012593, 
    0.0297542571267331, 0, 0.0363411597373587, 0.0464268327265193, 
    0.0397546685980086, 0.0425232243321057, 0.0491394530734343, 
    0, 0.0512205034016493, 0.023265025230139, 0.130162735781893, 
    0, 0.00172924583134173, 0.0151881345061173, 0, 0.00627947433627598, 
    0.0294566317536447, 0, 0.0219007314344687, 0.0325147743718963, 
    0.0217068035294528, 0.0421033329124698, 0.0598498279176085, 
    0.0367014804623366, 0, 0.0112685493245731, 0, 0.0244395279569477, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0284178332388335, 0.0172361640202619, 0, 0, 0.0696179025386967, 
    0, 0.0326894931500658, 0.0357040919746224, 0, 0, 0.0249178476389238, 
    0.0352610153819442, 0.0328734352013559, 0.0617545472865813, 
    0, 0.0207506171743469, 0, 0.0305444767848352, 0, 0.0929441779938578, 
    0, 0, 0.000862381695162522, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00915697077658768, 
    0.00519643795857245, 0.0307979644034479, 0, 0.00698472962155531, 
    0, 0.0199783989559414, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0254301231025472, 0.025047442952686, 
    0.0155766631515065, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0440960327498434, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.0534778164817806, 0, 0, 0.00561105591849906, 0.00152583336400935, 
    0.00254685239076886, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00527371088143689, 
    0, 0.0772390556432671, 0.0207322366441531, 0.0210830553970646, 
    0.0305955121797466, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0148437275520952, 0.00609710792304611, 
    0, 0.015981026580848, 0.025051785967936, 0.0389482816375524, 
    0.020349253455194, 0.0627993353586687, 0.00460242471652847, 
    0.0485561437472398, 0.0177526021445402, 0.0101673059715439, 
    0, 0.0903189541517896, 0.0580609789739699, 0, 0.0118961199427791, 
    0.0171458953775212, 0, 0.0603980271234423, 0, 0.00997382540549818, 
    0.0353123063840155, 0, 0.0180998050400415, 0.0387851152755127, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.00946566426999915, 0.0670054256699114, 0.0581969271065707, 
    0, 0, 0.0556965780292049, 0.0732627692515277, 0.0140112054771588, 
    0.00984541968035761, 0, 0.0717510559560799, 0, 0.00562112118206019, 
    0.0379345846067488, 0.0163576523536694, 0, 0.0550826497767126, 
    0, 0.0545136959738124, 0, 0.0367619707847923, 0, 0.0787717583492642, 
    0, 0.0132462917793894, 0.0404053542614469, 0, 0.0529231107041675, 
    0.0251568005977411, 0.0429367207295608, 0.00659646403949938, 
    0.00314633388123152, 0, 0.05683292058612, 0.0693337483074505, 
    0, 0.0052812377088224, 0.0603283878936135, 0.0175886895539951, 
    0.00684476786045868, 0.0502051812712609, 0.00931392406632221, 
    0.0246882020312601, 0.0154937998665694, 0.0220815197631123, 
    0.0325435714543445, 0.0543377785028446, 0.0485177228305912, 
    0.0049264995739426, 0.0262564606665425, 0, 0.0431262317620784, 
    0.0643052393755446, 0.0210436306987784, 0, 0.0244617147713927, 
    0.0525280224763613, 0.0312545726943389, 0.0573566498616491, 
    0.0954559509729238, 0, 0.055273928372713, 0.0689763282568183, 
    0), `CD8 T cells` = c(0.00282626493694126, 0.0225524838253428, 
    0, 0.0030508623462426, 0, 0.0128041131453121, 0, 0.102208367313482, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0668565430396047, 0.0343785834326558, 0, 0.0418137510155405, 
    0.0039045724524825, 0.0142647475514386, 0.0757110710314276, 
    0, 0.00193060219135434, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0610931845640821, 0, 
    0.00360600124042579, 0.0514577752685188, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0120924395079019, 
    0.0583407787656545, 0.0851792840684484, 0, 0.022134771398663, 
    0, 0.0211571093908383, 0.0807911110132147, 0.00750874397557059, 
    0.0254236631776496, 0.00036267330304203, 0, 0.0117215799165877, 
    0.00457999073294391, 0.0143804425928957, 0, 0.0343234519088158, 
    0.0939733560467514, 0.0121262147833725, 0.0443913493612884, 
    0.013913351266118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0825285153581206, 0.0703595057802011, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0127010702568596, 0, 0, 0, 0.0115250227619369, 
    0.0112073247871337, 0, 0, 0.0225575273021384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.0205653308221269, 0.0215329194725347, 0.0175703185581778, 
    0, 0, 0.0863636552001605, 0, 0.0246459273901821, 0, 0.0458061730920585, 
    0.0305151154470972, 0, 0.0108335554530586, 0, 0, 0, 0.0103242503772444, 
    0, 0.0210001416670375, 0, 0.00839436894394123, 0.0100506227977884, 
    0, 0, 0.0148028218053312, 0, 0, 0.0224063100187512, 0, 0.0453062352314343, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0279831576711753, 0, 0, 0, 0.0176994526150962, 
    0.0885582168017474, 0.0662308309228318, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0181057191077647, 
    0.0474226409710416, 0.148381299313082, 0.0953298762098904, 
    0, 0.0350837380941876, 0, 0, 0.038362571867775, 0.0401135257372477, 
    0.097256866037804, 0.0827139620004576, 0, 0.00131332939048673, 
    0, 0.00969154612033788, 0, 0.0373563100802613, 0.00132607110970266, 
    0.0190816512768151, 0.0104475637361147, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0.0116331725349049, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00644253388900522, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.0106094466963549, 0.0241129268386368, 0, 0.012355550014181, 
    0.0420728054331855, 0.0126437189193014, 0.00867377050916429, 
    0, 0.0753442695985309, 0, 0, 0.0643083403624027, 0.0502283193280119, 
    0, 0.0847152899905877, 0.00542245018607274, 0.042520862879495, 
    0.01017239957654, 0.0725952727243169, 0, 0, 0.0174462207779723, 
    0.0423963216858839, 0.0182656703532976, 0.0252909218873488, 
    0, 0.0247573127521529, 0.0394546977212568, 0.0233015751420834, 
    0, 0.0267097610602972, 0, 0.0216889663144949, 0, 0, 0, 0.122300803380855, 
    0.0648661351611547, 0.0495791769874816, 0), `NK cells` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0386903201290219, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.00355984445884494, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00767701457765108, 
    0.0587024011588043, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0162734423895632, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.0112353938770835, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00445713052647821, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0215162506970052, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00224916167727118, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `B cells` = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0158949534772194, 0, 0, 
    0.0174286273520171, 0, 0, 0.0240398020597407, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.00913877467242855, 0.00412289043242486, 0, 0.0110214512593062, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0.01395841549497, 0, 0, 0.0203618100888158, 0.00469314330089819, 
    0.00218217162335155, 0, 0, 0.000927389710308068, 0.00944356862980695, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00387880547179578, 0, 0, 0, 0.00135885903888649, 
    0.0211058465350401, 0.00475074203059272, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0057186076822505, 
    0, 0, 0.00767963556478094, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00490430962653799, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00400047092161493, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00296088758895798, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0.0272763742226307, 0.0143190468146728, 0, 0, 0.000380526692295014, 
    0, 0.00451965268329864, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0114107311910943, 0, 
    0, 0.00706169482835199, 0.00548790147180555, 0.00474878446333606, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.00490986172994977, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0091887199520897, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0102484731659565, 0, 0, 0, 0.000166713918956166, 
    0, 0.000687830346100619, 0.00462084816972582, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    2.78719370119586e-05, 0, 0, 0.00280672024739521, 0, 0.0012905492808203, 
    0, 0, 0, 0.00952459251673895, 0, 0, 0, 0.0304212599524777, 
    0.00403590718674567, 0.0144699621803493, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JO.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JQ.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93W.01A", 
"TCGA.4A.A93X.01A", "TCGA.4A.A93Y.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JU.01A", "TCGA.5P.A9JY.01A", 
"TCGA.5P.A9KE.01A", "TCGA.A4.7288.01A", "TCGA.A4.7583.01A", "TCGA.A4.7584.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7585.01A", "TCGA.A4.7734.01A", "TCGA.A4.7915.01A", "TCGA.A4.7996.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.7997.01A", "TCGA.A4.8098.01A", "TCGA.A4.8311.01A", "TCGA.A4.8517.01A", 
"TCGA.A4.8630.01A", "TCGA.A4.A57E.01A", "TCGA.AL.7173.01A", "TCGA.AL.A5DJ.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.5398.01A", "TCGA.B1.7332.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47M.01A", "TCGA.B1.A47N.01A", 
"TCGA.B1.A47O.01A", "TCGA.B1.A654.01A", "TCGA.B1.A657.01A", "TCGA.B3.8121.01A", 
"TCGA.B3.A6W5.01A", "TCGA.B9.5155.01A", "TCGA.B9.5156.01A", "TCGA.B9.7268.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A44B.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W7.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W8.01A", "TCGA.B9.A5W9.01A", 
"TCGA.B9.A69E.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YH.01A", "TCGA.B9.A8YI.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5875.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5877.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5878.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5879.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5880.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5881.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5882.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5883.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5885.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5887.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5888.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5889.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5890.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.5891.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5892.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5893.01A", "TCGA.BQ.5894.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7044.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7046.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7048.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7049.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7050.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7051.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7053.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7055.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7056.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7058.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7059.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7060.01A", 
"TCGA.BQ.7061.01A", "TCGA.BQ.7062.01A", "TCGA.DW.5560.01A", "TCGA.DW.5561.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7834.01A", "TCGA.DW.7837.01A", "TCGA.DW.7838.01A", "TCGA.DW.7839.01A", 
"TCGA.DW.7840.01A", "TCGA.DW.7841.01A", "TCGA.DW.7842.01A", "TCGA.DW.7963.01B", 
"TCGA.DZ.6131.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6132.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6133.01A", "TCGA.DZ.6134.01A", 
"TCGA.DZ.6135.01A", "TCGA.EV.5901.01A", "TCGA.EV.5902.01A", "TCGA.EV.5903.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A4JJ.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7Q0.01A", "TCGA.F9.A7VF.01A", "TCGA.F9.A8NY.01A", 
"TCGA.F9.A97G.01A", "TCGA.G7.6789.01A", "TCGA.G7.6790.01A", "TCGA.G7.6792.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.6793.01A", "TCGA.G7.6795.01A", "TCGA.G7.6796.01A", "TCGA.G7.6797.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.7501.01A", "TCGA.G7.7502.01A", "TCGA.G7.A4TM.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LB.01A", 
"TCGA.G7.A8LC.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LD.01A", "TCGA.G7.A8LE.01A", "TCGA.GL.6846.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.7773.01A", "TCGA.GL.7966.01A", "TCGA.GL.8500.01A", "TCGA.GL.A4EM.01A", 
"TCGA.GL.A59R.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DC.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DD.01A", "TCGA.GL.A9DE.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.7128.01A", "TCGA.HE.7129.01A", "TCGA.HE.7130.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NF.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NH.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NI.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NJ.01A", "TCGA.HE.A5NK.01A", 
"TCGA.HE.A5NL.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40U.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40X.01A", "TCGA.IA.A40Y.01A", 
"TCGA.IA.A83V.01A", "TCGA.IA.A83W.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8195.01A", "TCGA.IZ.8196.01A", 
"TCGA.IZ.A6M8.01A", "TCGA.J7.6720.01A", "TCGA.J7.8537.01A", "TCGA.J7.A8I2.01A", 
"TCGA.KV.A6GD.01A", "TCGA.KV.A6GE.01A", "TCGA.KV.A74V.01A", "TCGA.MH.A55Z.01A", 
"TCGA.MH.A560.01A", "TCGA.MH.A562.01A", "TCGA.MH.A855.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E6.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5E7.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5E8.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EA.01A", "TCGA.P4.A5EB.01A", 
"TCGA.P4.A5ED.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVL.01A", "TCGA.P4.AAVM.01A", "TCGA.PJ.A5Z8.01A", 
"TCGA.PJ.A5Z9.01A", "TCGA.Q2.A5QZ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71R.01A", "TCGA.SX.A71U.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SM.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SN.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SO.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SP.01A", 
"TCGA.SX.A7SQ.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SR.01A", "TCGA.SX.A7SS.01A", "TCGA.UN.AAZ9.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PJ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PK.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PL.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PM.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PN.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PO.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PP.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PR.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PS.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PU.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PV.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9PX.01A", 
"TCGA.UZ.A9PZ.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q0.01A", "TCGA.UZ.A9Q1.01A", "TCGA.V9.A7HT.01A", 
"TCGA.WN.A9G9.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A894.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A895.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A896.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A897.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RY.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8RZ.01A", "TCGA.Y8.A8S0.01A", 
"TCGA.Y8.A8S1.01A"))
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The matrix passed to the `Heatmap` function has row and column names that, once removed, will eliminate unwanted items. This can be done with the `rownames` and `colnames` functions.

See the code below, I've created the matrix in a separate line for clarity.

```
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("ComplexHeatmap")
library(ComplexHeatmap)

row_km = ncol(met.resolv)-1
ha = rowAnnotation(foo = anno_empty(border = FALSE, width = max_text_width(unlist(colnames(met.resolv))) + unit(row_km, "mm")))

met.resolv.matrix = as.matrix(met.resolv)
colnames(met.resolv.matrix) = NULL
rownames(met.resolv.matrix) = NULL

Heatmap(t(met.resolv.matrix), name = "mat", row_km = row_km, right_annotation = ha)
for(i in 1:row_km) {
    decorate_annotation("foo", slice = i, {
        grid.rect(x = 0, width = unit(2, "mm"), gp = gpar(fill = i, col = NA), just = "left")
        grid.text(paste(colnames(met.resolv)[[i]], collapse = "\n"), x = unit(4, "mm"), just = "left")
    })
}
```

[image]

Comment: @melolili Did my answer help at all?